# NumberFormatException not wrking java

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, input, try-catch

I'm new to this I can't figure it out how to break the loop.
`````````` Java```````````

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Enter number list:");

        try {
        String data = input.nextLine();
        ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int num;

        while (true){

            num = Integer.parseInt(data);

             myArray.add(num);}
    }

            catch  (NumberFormatException e)    { 
                e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: When must the loop stop?

Comment: That's impossible. If a `NumberFormatException` fires, it will be catched. Your issue is the `while (true)` loop, if the first input is valid it will never stop.

Comment: The `NumberFormatException` might have been caught, but you have hidden that by doing nothing in the `catch` block. Put a `System.err.println("NumberFormatException");` or a `e.printStackTrace();` there, at least...

Comment: Sidenote: Do not use empty catch blocks. At least log the exception. `e.printStacktrace();` In most cases `while(true)` is not what you want. Add an exit condition.

Comment: When you post a code you should properly intend the code for better readability.

Answer (score 3):

You should read new inputs inside your loop:

```
try {
    ...
    while (true) { 

        num = Integer.parseInt(data);

        myArray.add(num);
    }
}
catch  (NumberFormatException e)  {

};
```

Currently you are adding the same input infinite times to your `List`.

P.S. perhaps you shouldn't use an infinite while loop. How do you plan to finish reading the inputs? By catching a `NumberFormatException` when the user enters an invalid number? It's not a good practice to use exceptions as part of your logic.

Comment: try {
   ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in) ;
   System.out.println("Enter number list:");
   String data = input.nextLine();
   int num;
  
   num = Integer.parseInt(data);

   myArray.add(num);
  
   while (true){
   
   num = Integer.parseInt(data);  
  }} catch  (NumberFormatException e)    { 
   e.printStackTrace();
    } 
 }

Answer (score 0):

Thank you got it to work

```
while(true) {
        Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Please enter a number or anything else to stop:");
        String data = input.nextLine();
        int num;

     try{

        num = Integer.parseInt(data);
        myArray.add(num);
        int arraySize;

        arraySize = myArray.size();
        Collections.sort(myArray);


    }   catch  (NumberFormatException e)    { 
        break;       

        }
     }
}
```